# Is $Q=TS$ valid for externally reversible process or internally reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

For $q=tds$ is this equation valid for externally reversible process or internally reversible process? Like for example a heat transfer process in Rankine Cycle is internally reversible but not externally reversible so can we use for it $Q=TS$ EQUATION?

Comment: Who says that heat transfer is internally reversible in the Rankine cycle, but not externally reversible?  The equation $Q=T\Delta S$ typically applies only to an ideal constant temperature reservoir at its interface with whatever it is exchanging heat with.

Comment: Although the ideal Rankine cycle is internally reversible, there are still external irreversibilities because of the temperature change in the heat addition process. From : https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/internal-irreversibility#:~:text=Although%20the%20ideal%20Rankine%20cycle,and%20pumps%20are%20not%20isentropic.

Comment: @ChetMiller Does that statement in the link make sense to you? It doesn't to me.

Comment: This is just the idealized model of the process that they are specifying.  It might very well be a pretty good approximation.

Comment: @ChetMiller But they are saying the process for the ideal Rankine cycle is externally irreversible because the temperature changes. Just because the temperature changes doesn't mean its irreversible.

Comment: @BobD Sorry Bob.  I'm unable to find where it says that.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm referring to the following statement: "Although the ideal Rankine cycle is internally reversible, there are still external irreversibilities because of the temperature change in the heat addition process". I don't understand what that means. Do you?

Comment: @BobD I think what this means is that there is a finite temperature difference between the combustion gas and the evaporating water, and that most of this temperature difference resides on the combustion gas side of the boundary.  This is because the heat transfer coefficient on the combustion gas side of the boundary is much lower than on the evaporating liquid side of the boundary.

Comment: @ChetMiller So we have a case where the system undergoes a reversible cycle and yet there is an increase in the entropy of the surroundings? In other words $\Delta S_{tot}\gt 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$q=tds$ should be written

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

And therefore

$$\Delta S=\int\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

Although it is defined for a reversible transfer of heat, it can be used to calculate the change in entropy between two states for any process (reversible or irreversible) by assuming any convenient reversible process connecting the two states. One can do this because entropy is a state function independent of the process.

> Like for example a heat transfer process in Rankine Cycle is
> internally reversible but not externally reversible so can we use for
> it $Q=TS$ EQUATION?

It's not clear to me, from the link you provided to @Chet Miller, why a reversible Rankine cycle would be internally reversible but externally irreversible. The fact that temperature changes does not make a process irreversible, provided the difference in temperature between the heat source and water is infinitesimal.

But regardless, you can't use $Q=T\Delta S$ for the total heat addition in a Rankine cycle simply because the equation assumes there is only an isothermal (constant temperature) heat addition. For the Rankine cycle it is only constant temperature during the liquid to vapor transition in the boiler. The temperature changes when the boiler heats the water where it exits the pump until it reaches its boiling point. See the Rankine cyle diagram below. For a super heat Rankine cycle (not shown) the boiler additionally increases the temperature of the superheated steam before it enters the turbine.

In order to apply the second equation above for an ideal (reversible) Rankine cycle, one can assume a reversible heat addition process from $T_1$ to $T_2$. Such a process would involve heating the water with an infinite series of thermal reservoirs ranging between $T_1$ and $T_2$, the temperature of each being infinitesimally greater than the previous, with the temperature difference between the reservoir and water being always being infinitesimal to make the heat transfer reversible. Then, the entropy increase between $T_1$ and $T_2$ would be

$$\Delta S=\int_{T1}^{T{2}}\frac{dQ}{T}=\int_{T1}^{T{2}}\frac{CdT}{T}=C\ln\frac{T_{2}}{T_1}$$

Hope this helps.

[image]